# JavaScript Functions Callback

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I'm trying to read in some questions and answers from a database. The questions will be written to the page as text whereas the answers will be a drop down menu. i.e. What's your favorite color? blue,green,etc. My problem is that they don't appear in the right order. I call the getData function which enters a loop and gets the answers for each question. It enters the getAnswers function but doesn't go into the embedded function. It instead returns to the getData function and completes all the questions before going into the function and getting the answers. This causes all the questions to be printed out and then all the answers. I want it to be a question followed by it's answer and so on. I have tried getting rid of the extra functions and putting everything into one function but it still didn't work and made the code hard to read. I think this is caused by JavaScript's function callback but don't know enough about JavaScript to be certain. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function getData(){
            $.getJSON("questions.php", "",
                function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                        $("#divButton").append($('<p>' + val.question + '</p>'));
                        getAnswers(val.questionID);

                    });
                }
            );
        }

function getAnswers(questionID){
            //Gets to here when first called
            $.getJSON("answers.php",{id:questionID},
                function(data){
                    //Doesn't get to here until all questions have been written to page
                    var string = "<select>";
                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                        string += "<option>" + val.answer + "</option>";
                    });
                    string += "</select></br>";
                    $("#divButton").append($(string));
                }
            );
        }
```

Comment: The issue is that $.getJson is an asynchronous operation. it does happen, but your function would have returned already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return handler to `getAnswers` will happen after you have written out all of the questions.

One solution is to pass in the question element, so getAnswers knows where to insert the results:

```
function getData(){
            $.getJSON("questions.php", "",
                function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                        var question = $('<p>' + val.question + '</p>')
                                         .appendTo($('#divButton'));
                        getAnswers(val.questionID, question);

                    });
                }
            );
        }

function getAnswers(questionID, questionElement){
            //Gets to here when first called
            $.getJSON("answers.php",{id:questionID},
                function(data){
                    //Doesn't get to here until all questions have been written to page
                    var string = "<select>";
                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                        string += "<option>" + val.answer + "</option>";
                    });
                    string += "</select></br>";
                    $(string).insertAfter(questionElement);
                }
            );
        }
```